# How do I install an .rpm that fails with an error about an .so file not being found from Python 2.6?

Tags: centos, python, rpm, compatibility, hadoop

When I try to install cloudera-manager-agent 5.7 from an .rpm I get an error.  The error says that a dependency has not been met because yum could not find libpython2.6.so.1.0(64bit).  I would expect Python 2.7 to be supported with Cloudera 5.7.  Cloudera 5.7 is new, and Python 2.6 is old.

I am using Python 2.7.5 on CentOS 7.2  Should I downgrade to Python 2.6?  I'm concerned that many things will stop working.  How do I get this dependency (related to Python 2.6) to be met to install Cloudera-Manager-Agent?  I think this file would need to be registered with the yum package manager.  But I need to get the file on the OS first.  However, I do not know if something related to Python 2.6 can work with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Actuall how many application on your centos 7.2 depended on python 2.7? You can not do downgrade when python 2.7 was default from centos 7.2. My suggestion : downgrade centos 7.2 to centos 6.8.Or you want to install python 2.6 manually and download it from rpm.pbone.net.And you should remove python 2.7 from centos 7.2